# DIV Boxes responsive

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I am working in a WordPress environment without access to the CSS :(.

I have 4 div boxes currently displaying side by side by using:

```css
<style> .cells {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="cells" style="width: 20.5%; height: 175px; margin: 0 20px 0 0; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;">
    <h3>this is box one</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cells" style="width: 20.5%; height: 175px; margin: 0 20px 0 0; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;">
    <h3>this is box two</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cells" style="width: 20.5%; height: 175px; margin: 0 20px 0 0; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;">
    <h3>this is box three</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cells" style="width: 20.5%; height: 175px; margin: 0 20px 0 0; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;">
    <h3>this is box four</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
```

the boxes display side by side just fine on the page but I need to get them to flow down the page on various mobile devices.

I am not sure how to do this, can someone please offer some advice?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you have access to the CSS?  At worst, can you inline the CSS, that is: add the `<style>` tag inline with media queries end all?  If you really don't have any access to any CSS at all, there's not much to be done.  Unless you have access to JavaScript?

Comment: Please expand on the exact desired behavior, "flow down" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another has said in a comment to your question, the question is a little vague and it is difficult to determine exactly what you are looking for. I *think* you mean that you want them to all have 100% width on mobile devices and stack one underneath the other as opposed to left to right. But, again, only on mobile devices.

Well, you would need to use a media query to set new behaviors for the divs *only* on mobile devices device's below a certain screen width (lets say 480 like a galaxy s4 or something and set aside the pixel ratio stuff)

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .cells {
        clear:both; 
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

^ That should ensure each one takes up the full width and will not hang up on one another's edges but clear down to the next line.

I hope that gets you started with what you want to do.